# Showing a function is discontinuous using open sets

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am experimenting with the following theorem:

> A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(O)$
>   is open in A for every open set $O\subset B$.

I am trying to find an open set in the range of the following function to show that it is discontinuous. What is such a set? 
$$f:[-1, 1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$
f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      x & x<0 \\
      x-1 & x\geqslant0
   \end{cases}
$$

I tried using intervals such as: $(-0.5, 0)$ and $(0, 0.5)$ but they led me nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $O=\left(-\frac32,-\frac12\right)$. Compute $f^{-1}(O)$ and you will see that it is not an open subset of $[-1,1]$.